# Does PostgreSQL do the caching like applications do?

Tags: postgresql, cache

Applications usually cache data on an implementation of hash data structures to speed up the query, typically Memcached or Redis. Does relational databases also do the same things internally?

For example, if I do the `select * from account where id = 1` where `id` isn't indexed or b-tree indexed, does the engine caches the result to the cache using the key like `account_id_1` so that the subsequent same queries could return the result from the cache until it's invalidated?

I'm asking this because I saw the following from the [FoundationDB's documentation](https://apple.github.io/foundationdb/features.html), and wondered whether that feature is something new for FoundationDB or relational databases have been doing this also although it's not distributed:

> Distributed Caching
>
> When your database scales out, you don’t need a separate distributed
>   caching layer: you already have one. FoundationDB uses the aggregate
>   memory of the entire cluster to cache commonly accessed data. Unlike a
>   caching tier such as memcached, FoundationDB’s cache is completely
>   synchronized to the database and provides all ACID guarantees.

Comment: See [here](https://madusudanan.com/blog/understanding-postgres-caching-in-depth/) or [here](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/media/pdfs/talks/InsideBufferCache.pdf)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can only find the caching of pages from your links, not the whole query results.

Comment: that's correct. Postgres only caches pages (blocks of data)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Then could you unmark this question as duplicated? Maybe someone can give insight into why postgres or other relational databases doesn't do that while FoundationDB does.

Comment: Well Postgres _does_ cache the "result". It caches the data that was read from the disk to build the result. The question "_Why_ does Postgres cache it this way" isn't a good fit for dba.stackexchange.com to begin with. It's a design decision done by the developers ages ago - if at all, you should ask that on the Postgres mailing list. Also "query caches" aren't usually a good idea in a transactional database where two different executions of the same query could yield two completely different results. MySQL/MariaDB used to have that, but I think they removed it in recent version

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's correct, but my question was about the kind of caching that avoids traversing b-tree data structures or whole table scan, and I gave a specific example of it. If 'why' part of my comments isn't fit for here, just ignore it, it wasn't part of my original question. Anyway I don't think my question is duplicated, and If you write your comment of 'Postgres only caches pages' as an answer, I can mark it as accepted if someone doesn't give better answer.